# Rewriting sql query without subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I need some help with the followin MySQL Query

I want to rewrite my Query without any subqueries - but i dont know how..

It is a video rental store database ;)

```
SELECT k.first_name, k.last_name, SUM(amount) AS profit 
FROM payment AS p 
JOIN (SELECT c.* FROM customer AS c 
 JOIN rental AS r ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id 
WHERE r.return_date IS NULL GROUP BY c.customer_id HAVING 
COUNT(*) > '1') AS k ON p.customer_id = k.customer_id 
GROUP BY k.customer_id 
HAVING SUM(amount) > 100 
ORDER BY profit DESC;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to remove the sub-query?  This seems a perfectly reasonable way of doing things, and not all requirements can be expressed without sub-queries.  Have you checked the EXPLAIN plan to see if there is something in particular you want to 'fix'?

Comment: I want do remove the sub query.. cuase my teacher asked for / home work. And i like join more then sub queries ;)

Comment: Note to self:  Do not hire people who cannot complete their own homework.

Comment: note... my homework was to write an query whichs works and it works - it is only for my own interest...

Comment: That is not what your comment above states...

Comment: Yeah... sorry - i'm a german guy and my english isn't perfect ;D

Comment: It's odd that there might be a row in a table called 'rental' that had `date` set as null. Under what circumstances might this occur?

Comment: The value is null if the movie was not returned ;)

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
 SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, c.customer_id,SUM(amount) AS profit 
 FROM payment AS p 
    INNER JOIN (customer c
        INNER join rental r
        ON c.customer_id=r.customer_id)
    ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.customer_id,c.last_name,c.first_name
 HAVING SUM(amount) > 100 
 ORDER BY profit DESC;
```

using INNER JOIN will restrict this query to only those customers who have made payments.

Comment: The homework was to write a query - i had done this and its works fine - but after 3 hours i dont know what to do... ;)

Comment: trying joining payment directly to customer and customer directly to rental.  It may also help to specify LEFT, RIGHT, or INNER.

Comment: Okay my sql code looks like yours :) But where can i definde the count(*) > 1? The query should show people wich have borrowed 2 movies at the moment << this is my biggest problem..:/ i tryed to put it in the where but it doesn't work (sorry for my english ;) )

Comment: Joining on to `rental` for customers with more than one *current* rental is going to cause duplication of data *(`n` payment records, which relate to 1 `customer` record, which relate to `m` rental records, giving a total of `m*n` rows*).  You need to eliminate that 1:many relationship on `rental` before this will work without a sub-query or correlated sub-query.  @tobias - Please could you show the schema for all of the tables?  It is possible that each record in `payment` corresponds to exactly 1 record in `rental`.  If so, then you can use that to eliminate the 1:many relationship.

Comment: @tobias - Under what circumstances can one `rental` record relate to *many* `payment` records?

Comment: @tobias - Oh my, and how can a payment not relate to a rental?  The relationship is `0..1 rentals : 1..many payments`.  I don't understand this relationship design.

Comment: Well, i don't know ;) This database schema is only for training our sql skills in/on (?) selecting over more then one table ;) There are no 1 rental to many payment records - i hope you understand me :D well there are some foreign key checks ..